# Como puedo hacer transparente el fondo del widget en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo un screen donde se muestra una imagen y una frase, la imagen va cambiando de tamaño excepto la frase, pero el fondo de este screen se ve color negro y necesito que el fondo sea un poco transparente.

otra duda que me surge es como puedo utilizar este screen para digamos del screenA pase a este screen y luego al screenB algo asi para usarlo como una pequeña transicion, eh intento realizarlo, pero no eh tenido éxito en intento.

les anexo el código fuente del screen que digamos es la animación de la que quiero hacer un poco transparente el fondo y esta misma me servirá como transición de un screen a otro

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class IndicatorProgress extends StatefulWidget {
  const IndicatorProgress({Key? key});
  static const String name = 'indicator_progress_screen';

  @override
  State<IndicatorProgress> createState() => _IndicatorProgressState();
}

class _IndicatorProgressState extends State<IndicatorProgress> {
  double _size = 20.0;
  final double _maxSize = 60.0;
  bool _isMounted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isMounted = true;
    startAnimation();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isMounted = false;
    super.dispose();
  }

  void startAnimation() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 16), (timer) {
      if (_isMounted) {
        if (_size <= _maxSize) {
          setState(() {
            _size += 0.9;
          });
        }
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Center(
        
        child: Stack(
          
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            AnimatedSize(
              
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: Container(
                width: _size,
                height: _size,
                child: Image.asset('assets/imagenes/logo.png'),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                child: Text(
                  'Procesando...',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'PublicaSans',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... ¿Opacity?

Comment: debajo del scaffold?

Comment: Revisá las propiedades de [`Image.asset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html). Luego, revisá las propiedades de la animación [`Opacity`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html).